# Flaw in this proof (direct sum of modules)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

I am trying to prove the following: If $$\bigoplus_{i\in I}\alpha_iN_i\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I}\beta_iN_i$$ where $N_i$ are distinct simple modules, then $$\alpha_i=\beta_i$$ for all $i\in I$.

It is intuitively obvious, but my textbook and lecture notes seems to prove it in a very long way. (e.g. Richard Pierce's textbook on Associative Algebras Page 32).

Hence, I have a feeling something is not quite right with my shorter proof presented below, however I don't know which part is wrong:

(My attempt) Let $\alpha_1n_1+\dots+\alpha_kn_k\in\bigoplus_{i\in I}\alpha_iN_i$.
Then it can also be written as $\alpha_1n_1+\dots+\alpha_kn_k=\beta_1n_1+\dots+\beta_ln_l\in\bigoplus_{i\in I}\beta_iN_i$.

Since $N_i\not\cong N_j$ for $i\neq j$, the above direct sums can be viewed as internal direct sum. By property of internal direct sum (any element can be written uniquely), $k=l$ and $\alpha_i=\beta_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$. Since $k$ is arbitrary, $\beta_i=\alpha_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Thanks for helping me find the mistake in the argument above.

Update: Sorry for the confusion. Serious misinterpretation by me. $\alpha_iN_i$ actually means the direct sum of $N_i$ with itself $\alpha_i$ times.

Comment: @yoyostein I don't see any $\;\gamma_i\;$ in page 32 of Pierce's book. Do you have another version of this theorem?

Comment: Are you sure this statement is true? For instance $\mathbb F_5$ is a simple $\mathbb Z$-module, and it seems to me that $2\mathbb F_5 = \mathbb 3 F_5$ while $2 \neq 3$. But I am probably missing something obvious.

Comment: @Joanpemo I am proving a variant that is highly similar to page 32 of Pierce's book. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Seconding Marc Paul's comment. Something is seriously wrong here. If $N$ is a simple module over a commutative ring $R$, then $\alpha N= N=1N$ for any $\alpha\in R$ such that $\alpha N\neq\{0\}.$ Proof: $\alpha N$ is a submodule of $N$. Because $N$ is simple, we have either $\alpha N=N$ or $\alpha N=\{0\}$, as a simple module has no non-trivial submodules.

Comment: Are, for example, the $\alpha_i$s and $\beta_i$s supposed to be natural numbers, and the author uses the notation that $\alpha N$ means the direct sum of $\alpha$ copies of $N$? This is IMO an unusual notation, but one interpretation that would actually make the statement true (by Jordan-Hölder)!

Comment: Can you just tell us what the $\alpha$s and $\beta$s are? You try to use them as elements of the ring $R$ the $N_i$s are modules over, but in that case the claim is so false it hurts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right. I made a serious misinterpretation. $\alpha N$ means the direct sum of $\alpha$ copies of $N$.